# Do I need to return "render" in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

Is that return necessary? Let's say it's in the middle of an action.

```
render(contentType:'text/json', text: ['success': true] as JSON)    
return
```

Comment: @Don - What's the difference between mine and your edit?

Comment: functionally, they may be the same, but I think it's a lot easier to read now. If you disagree, feel free to revert my change

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you don't return, any code after `render` will also be executed, which is often not what you want, e.g.

```
def someAction = {

  if (someCondition) {
    render view: 'success'
    // if we don't return execution would fall through to the code below
    return  
  }

  log.error 'something went wrong'
  render view: 'error'
}
```

Of course, if you use this style instead, there's no need to return

```
def someAction = {

  if (someCondition) {
    render view: 'success'

  } else {    
    log.error 'something went wrong'
    render view: 'error'
  }
}
```

If an action only has one exit point, there's no need to return after `render`

```
def someAction = {
    render view: 'success'
}
```

Just remember that the code after `render` will be executed if you don't return.